# Scrapy Extract value of a tag

Tags: python, scrapy

I am doing my scrapy code where I have to extract data from website https://lemkus.com/collections/maylee/products/hannah-green-cord-pants?variant=43116172181756

Now Output should be like if item is out of stock only then show out_of_stock='True' along with size and otherwise dont show out_of_stock

Sample JSON output:

```
 "skus": [
  {
    "currency": "ZAR",
    "out_of_stock": true,
    "price": 850.00,
    "size": "8"
  },
  {
    "currency": "ZAR",
    "price": 850.00,
    "size": "10"
  },
  {
    "currency": "ZAR",
    "out_of_stock": true,
    "price": 850.00,
    "size": "12"
  },
  {
    "currency": "ZAR",
    "price": 850.00,
    "size": "14"
  }
```

The HTML Cde of website is:

```
        <fieldset class="fieldset-var  unavailable-product" data-var-id="43116172181756">
          
          <input class="js-variant-radio" name="id" type="radio" id="variant-1" value="43116172181756" data-inventory-qty="0">
          <label for="variant-1">8</label>
        </fieldset>  
    
        <fieldset class="fieldset-var variant-active " data-var-id="43116172214524">
          
          <input class="js-variant-radio" name="id" type="radio" id="variant-2" value="43116172214524" data-inventory-qty="1">
          <label for="variant-2">10</label>
        </fieldset>  
    
        <fieldset class="fieldset-var  unavailable-product" data-var-id="43116172247292">
          
          <input class="js-variant-radio" name="id" type="radio" id="variant-3" value="43116172247292" data-inventory-qty="0">
          <label for="variant-3">12</label>
        </fieldset>  
    
        <fieldset class="fieldset-var  " data-var-id="43116172280060">
          
          <input class="js-variant-radio" name="id" type="radio" id="variant-4" value="43116172280060" data-inventory-qty="1">
          <label for="variant-4">14</label>
        </fieldset>
```

OK, So in the HTML Code above,see where the tag "data-inventory-qty" is equal to zero and in some fields its greater than 0
I want to do is if data-inventory-qty="0", Show out_of_stock='True' otherwise don't show out of stock

I have logic for extracting currency,price and size. I just need the out_of_stock by extracting the value of data-inventory-qty or using another attribute that might work.

A part of the code for out_of_stock I have done until now is

```
items=response.xpath('//div//form//div//fieldset//input[@data-inventory-qty])'.getall()
```

I need Like there are 4 sizes in the above code so make a list of 4 data.
if data-inventory-qty is 0 with first item then append 'True' in the list otherwise append '' in the list.

So list for above HTML should be like ['','True','','True']

Comment: what is your current output stored in 'items'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
lst = response.xpath('//input[@class="js-variant-radio"]/@inventory-qty').getall()
result = [True if not int(i) else '' for i in lst]
print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
[True, '', True, '']
```

Comment: BTW Do you have another alternative? using response.css

Comment: Im actually not very well versed on the css selector. But something like `input.js-variant-radio ::inventory-qty` im just kind of guessing though based on what I have seen.  Ive never taken the time to actually learn the structure since all they are is xpath expressions with an added layer of abstraction. please don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Comment: or if that didnt work try `'input.js-variant-radio::attrib(inventory-qty)'`  and if that doesn't work try `response.css('input.js-variant-radio').attrib('inventory-qty').get()`  one of those 3 should work